# Set limit for IN condition element that evaluate true

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table: t
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| Id           | price     | Date      |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1           | 30        | 2021-05-09|
|  1           | 24        | 2021-04-26|
|  1           | 33        | 2021-04-13|
|  2           | 36        | 2021-04-18|
|  3           | 15        | 2021-04-04| 
|  3           | 33        | 2021-05-06|
|  4           | 46        | 2021-02-16|
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to select rows where id is 1,2,4 and get maximum 2 row for each id by date descending order.

```
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| Id           | price     | Date      |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1           | 30        | 2021-05-09|
|  1           | 24        | 2021-04-26|
|  2           | 36        | 2021-04-18|
|  4           | 46        | 2021-02-16|
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Something like:

```
Select * from t where Id IN ('1','2','4') limit 2 order by Date desc;
```

this will limit the overall result fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select id, price, date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where id in (1, 2, 4)
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Probably the most efficient method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (1, 2, 4) and
      t.date >= coalesce( (select t2.date
                           from t t2
                           where t2.id = t.id
                           order by t2.date desc
                           limit 1,1
                           ), t.date
                        );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(id, date)`.  Also, this can return duplicates if there are multiple rows for a given id on the same date.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5caeaa072cd6fabe146e24a710eb0ca) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: assuming that there will be thousands of records for each id..then if I m not wrong the inner subquery will going to fetch all those thousands rows, lets say for Id "1" and then assign row numbers to all those records. (wouldn't that cause a performance issue to fetch all the records and select only 2 or 3 latest records by date?)

Comment: @user2248435 Get the execution plan and see. It'll probably depend on the available indexes.

Comment: @user2248435 . . . A correlated subquery (with the right index) can be more efficient than `row_number()`.  Usually the difference is not particularly significant, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, the 2nd approach will work good. Anyway to define  limit by date?. Right now it will only fetch latest row (one row) by Date for each id.

Comment: @user2248435 . . . Yes, of course.  I fixed the answer so it is appropriate to your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried your answer. it does look perfectly good. but idk why it return ok Message on workbench with NO result grid. this is the actual query that i m making:

`select * from Price04 A WHERE A.CUSIP IN ('594918104', '482170107', '471718205') 
AND (A.PrimaryExchgCD = A.ExchgCD or A.ExchgCD = 'USOTCB')
and A.MktCloseDate >= coalesce( (select B.MktCloseDate FROM  Price04 B WHERE B.CUSIP=A.CUSIP order by B.MktCloseDate desc limit 1,3),A.MktCloseDate) order by CUSIP desc, A.MktCloseDate desc;`

Comment: @user2248435 . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  It returns exactly what the question specifies.